# Can't update installed packages in AVD Manager

Tags: android, basic4android

I've recently tried to add packages to the SDK through the AVD Manager but I get file not found as an error when the manager goes out to find available packages. I looked at the SDK website but didn't find any resolution.

It looks like for some reason the repository path may have changed but I don't see a way to change it in the Manager.

So basically I don't see any available packages.

I wanted to install the 3.x packages to support tablets. If anyone has any idea I would appreciate any input.

thanks

Comment: Try to download and install the latest SDK manager.

Comment: Did you tried updating the SDK and AVD manager first.

Comment: Do you Use Eclipse if  you use it then First Update ADT Plugins and Go to Help->Install New Software then add this ADT Link to check it is install or not .ADT Plugin - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

Solution:

Download the latest [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
and then the lastest [SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r15-windows.exe) for your OS.

After setting up, downloading required packages should be easy.

Ensure your connection doesn't have a proxy, if it has you will required the necessary credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall, download a fresh version and reinstall the entire program, it was recently updated to a new version, maybe yours missed out?